# Setting GPO security filter with powershell (add delete computers)

Tags: security, powershell, filtering, gpo

I've been looking for a powershell script that can add a .csv file of servers to my previous configured GPO.

The case is that we constantly add new machines and because security groups of computers don't cut the chase (the policies don't get applied) I wanted a powershell to add a list of machines to my current GPO.

The trick is that it should delete first the current security filtering and then add the machines listed in the csv file.

Any help will be welcome.